# Base64 is too large to open in a browser, any alternatives?

Tags: javascript, pdf, base64, blob

My base64 PDF is too large that when I try and open it in a window, the url isn't pasted. I then substring'd it and the link would paste but of course.. it doesn't open as it hasn't received the whole base64.

Code:

```
   $.ajax({
    url: [database-url-here],
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      var pdf = (data.pdf).toString();

      window.open(pdf);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var w = window.open('', '', 'width=400,height=240'); // open blank page
w.document.write(
  '<embed type="application/pdf" ' +
         'width="400" height="240" ' +
         'src="data:application/pdf;base64,' + pdf + '">'
);
```

Comment: Didn't work :/ The base64 still didn't paste into the browser URL.

Comment: Possible your data in `pdf` variable is malformed. Or if you tried `window.open(pdf);` you also can try to set `src` in this way: `'src="' + pdf + '">'` (in case `data:application/pdf;base64,` already is in pdf variable).

Comment: I've tested this code in Firefox and its works for me.

Comment: It works, but it doesn't paste it when there are too may base64 characters for the browser

Comment: Yep, 5mb pdf opening about 20 secs. You can also try https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/

Answer (score 1):

For too big base64 pdf files I convert it to blob and then create a new URL from that blob.
Blob URL is much smaller then base64 url.

To convert I do something like this:

```
var url = 'data:application/pdf;base64,'+ base64string;
var blobUrl;
fetch(URL)
 .then(res => res.blob())
 .then(URL.createObjectURL)
 .then((ret) => {blobUrl=ret; return blobUrl;})
 .then(console.log)
```

One can test [at this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DnlCYan/5zfj3cb4/12/) at example 2.
Or see other alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36183085/3199081)